# tomcat eclipse mssql driver demanding Java 1.6

Tags: servlets, java-5

I started writing my servlet in Java 1.6 for tomcat 7, but then I later needed to roll back to Java 1.5 for tomcat 6.  I'm using eclipse.  For some reason though, when I try to run my servlet it gives me the following error:

**SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver.  Please use the JDBC 4 driver (sqljdbc4.jar) instead.
Jun 20, 2011 12:33:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Auth threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver.  Please use the JDBC 4 driver (sqljdbc4.jar) instead.**

Now originally I had sqljdbc4.jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory but I swapped it out for sqljdbc.jar so that it would be 1.5 compatible.  That's when I started getting the error.  Hunting around in the properties panels, I saw that JVM 1.6 was still in the Build Path libraries so I deleted those.  But now it can't find HTTPServlet!

I added back a servlet.jar file I had but it just gives me the "version 1.6 is not supported by this driver" message.  Curiously, I also have to use the oracle jdbc driver for this servlet and it is not giving me these errors when I backgraded the project and the driver jar to the 1.5 compatible version.

How do I get the eclipse project to not think it is 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the `Java` facet from `1.6` to `1.5`:

Project properties → *Project Facets → Java → 1.5*

[image]

Comment: oh, I should have probably mentioned that I did that already (that helped me reslove an earlier error but not this one).

Comment: Another thing I found in the Properties panel:  "When selecting 1.5 compliance, make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activated (currently 1.6)."  Now I do have 1.5 installed, but I'm not sure what they mean by "activated".

Comment: You can have more than 1 JRE/JDK installed on your computer; you can make more than 1 registered in Eclipse. "Activated" means, basically "selected for use with this workspace/project."

Comment: Okay, so that's probably not it.  But then why am I getting the 1.6 error if I have everything set to 1.5?

Comment: I can't see your project settings so I'm not sure. I'd start by removing all references to anything JRE/JVM/JDK 1.6 in Eclipse, adding back in what's needed for 1.5.

Comment: I've been through the properties panel, the preferences...I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Well, I think I finally figured it out.  It's Tomcat that's complaining, not Eclipse!  I finally dug into things and found out that my development machine is running tomcat 6 but with JVM 1.6!  So hopefully if anybody else gets this error, check your tomcat JVM to avoid chasing rabbits all over the eclipse menus.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I'm curious to know why all the JVM version jumping was necessary in the first place.